# Reconciling types React.FC with ReactElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Instead of hard-coding my routes in my App component, I've defined a Routes.ts file:

```js
import Login from "../components/Login/Login";
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import PageNotFound from "../components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";
import {ReactElement, ReactNode} from "react";

const routes: Array<{
    path: string,
    component: ReactElement,
    is_private: boolean
}> = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Login,
        is_private: false
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        is_private: true
    },
    {
        path: '/*',
        component: PageNotFound,
        is_private: false
    }
];

export default routes;
```

Which I then use like so:

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            {routes.map((route) => (
                <Route path={route.path}
                       key={route.path}
                       element={route.component} />
            ))}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, since my components are of type `React.FC` I can't get them to satisfy the ReactElement type:

```
TS2739: Type 'FunctionComponent<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>': type, props, key
```

I've tried:

- Changing the components to JSX.Element
- component: ReactNode
- component: FC

But none of those work as the types of my component (FC) and the type expected by Route.element (ReactElement) are not reconcilable.

I've even tried changing component to `any` type, which does compile, but results in runtime error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

Would anyone be so kind to nudge my in the right direction?

Comment: pls provide reproducible example

Comment: did you try providing `component={route.component}` instead of `element=`

Comment: https://www.harrymt.com/blog/2020/05/20/react-typescript-react-fc.html just dropping this here, might be helpful to know

Comment: @SinanYaman component no longer exists in the react-router-dom version I'm using, AFAIK it has been renamed to element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `routes` array allow any kind of component (FC, or otherwise), you can set the type to be `React.JSXElementConstructor`. This prevents the need to define all components as `FC`. This type takes an argument of the props, but if you don't care about the props, you can just set it to `any`:

```
const routes: Array<{
    path: string,
    component: React.JSXElementConstructor<any>,
    is_private: boolean
}> = [
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you type your components in your routes array as `ReactElement`? Have you tried using `FC` instead?

Stating that this is an array of ReactElements will clash with ReactRouters expected types. However, I guess your page components are in fact of React.FC type?

```
import Login from "../components/Login/Login";
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import PageNotFound from "../components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";
import {FC, ReactNode} from "react";

const routes: Array<{
    path: string,
    component: FC,
    is_private: boolean
}> = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Login,
        is_private: false
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        is_private: true
    },
    {
        path: '/*',
        component: PageNotFound,
        is_private: false
    }
];


const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            {routes.map((route) => (
                <Route path={route.path}
                       key={route.path}
                       element={route.component as } />
            ))}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```